# How can you mimic the description output?

Tags: swift, class, dynamictype

Imagine a class Fruit:

```
class Fruit: NSObject {
    override var description:String {
        return super.description
    }
}

var apple = Fruit()
var banana = Fruit()

print(apple)  // Output: <MyProject.Fruit: 0x7fa719627e00>
print(banana) // Output: <MyProject.Fruit: 0x7fa71962dab0>
```

**Question: How can you mimic this ouput?**

I currently have the following:

```
class Fruit: NSObject {
    override var description:String {
        print(super.description)
        return "<\(NSStringFromClass(self.dynamicType)): 0x\(String(self.hash, radix:16))>"
    }
}
```

Which now outputs the following:

```
<MyProject.Fruit: 0x7fb958c289a0>
<MyProject.Fruit: 0x7fb958c289a0>
<MyProject.Fruit: 0x7fb958c22df0>
<MyProject.Fruit: 0x7fb958c22df0>
```

As you can see the output is the same which is what I wanted. Now I am wondering if this is the proper way to mimic it's output or that I am overlooking something as mentioned in the comments below.

*Credits: Matt, Martin R and Vacawama*

Comment: How is your class defined? What would `self.description` print if you don't override it?

Comment: "This gave me the exact same output print(super.description) would do" No it doesn't, because the hash is not the memory address. This seems to be a case of failing to ask the question to which you actually wanted the answer...

Comment: I am sorry let me rewrite the question.

Comment: I rewrote the question, is this better?

Comment: @Mark: And if you don't override the description method then you get the same output because then the description method is inherited from NSObject.

Comment: Why do you need to "mimic" its output? You already _inherit_ its output. If you don't implement `description`, `self.description` _is_ `super.description`.

Comment: I like to do my own format and extend it, but I want the same values. So if I could mimic it I can format it any way I see fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any subclass of `NSObject` inherits the
[`description`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/description) method of `NSObject` (which is defined in the `NSObjectProtocol`):

```
class Foo1 : NSObject { }
print(Foo1())
// <MyProject.Foo1: 0x100612fd0>
```

This "default implementation" prints the class name and the memory
address of the object, see for example 
[Friday Q&A 2013-01-25: Let's Build NSObject](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2013-01-25-lets-build-nsobject.html), where it is shown how the Objective-C implementation
could look like:

```
- (NSString *)description
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"<%@: %p>", [self class], self];
}
```

The `%p` format prints the value of a pointer as a hexadecimal number,
preceded by `0x`.

To mimic that in Swift, we can use

- `String(reflecting: self.dynamicType)` which returns the fully-qualified class name as a string, and
- `unsafeAddressOf(self)` which returns a pointer to the storage
  of the object.

Example (using square brackets `[]` to demonstrate that the
overridden method is used):

```
class Foo2 : NSObject {
    override var description : String {
        let className = String(reflecting: self.dynamicType)
        let address = unsafeAddressOf(self)
        return String(format: "[%@: %p]", className, address)
    }
}
print(Foo2())
// [MyProject.Foo2: 0x100613310]

class Foo3 : Foo2 { }
print(Foo3())
// [MyProject.Foo3: 0x102000540]
```

This works for "pure Swift classes" as well, because no Foundation
methods are used:

```
class Bar : CustomStringConvertible {
    var description : String {
        let className = String(reflecting: self.dynamicType)
        let address = unsafeAddressOf(self)
        return String(format: "[%@: %p]", className, address)
    }
}
print(Bar())
// [MyProject.Bar: 0x102001200]
```

Note that (as already mentioned in above comments), the hash value
of an object is not necessarily identical to the memory address.
A simple example is `NSArray()` whose hash value is just the number
of elements:

```
let array = NSArray(objects: 1, 2, 3)
print(unsafeAddressOf(array)) // 0x00000001020011a0
print(array.hashValue) // 3
```

---

**Update for Swift 3:**

```
class Bar : CustomStringConvertible {
    var description : String {
        let className = String(reflecting: type(of: self))
        let address = Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque()
        return "[\(className): \(address)]"
    }
}
```

Comment: Amazing answer Martin R, thanks for your time and efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Use `String(self.hash, radix:16)`.  You might need to prefix the `0x` yourself.

Comment: Alternatively: `String(format: "%#x", hash)`, the '#' format flag causes '0x' to be prepended :)

Comment: You are both heroes... can't mark it as answer (9minutes and counting)

Comment: However, I'm guessing that this is a misunderstanding. The hash is not the memory address.

Comment: @MartinR, he might need `"%#lx"` for the larger number.

Comment: @vacawama: You are right, it depends on whether you are on a 32- or 64-bit platform. `String(format: "%#zx", hash)` would work in either case because *accidentally*, `Int` and `size_t` have the same size. matt's suggestion is probably the best.

Comment: @Mark: Expanding on matt's above comment ("The hash is not the memory address"): What you *really* might be looking for is `unsafeAddressOf()` which returns a pointer to the memory location.

Comment: I found that on the net as well, however it seems the hash also returns the memory address as `unsafeAddressOf()` returns the same but includes more zeros.

Comment: "it seems the hash also returns the memory address" Perhaps, but that's just an implementation detail. I wouldn't count on it if I were you. The hash is for hashing. You should say what you mean and not make magic assumptions.

Comment: Also, if you were to implement Equatable on this object, you would also need to implement `hash` differently, so that the hash would _really_ no longer be the memory address (since two different instances might have the same hash).

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, I thought the hash would be unique to every object. So the best way to check if an object is actually the same is by comparing it's memory address with unsafeAddressOf()?