# Why doesn't my instance get deallocated?

Tags: swift, memory-management

I have a Person class as below:

```
class Person{
    var name: String?

    init(name: String){
        self.name = name
    }
    func doWithDelay(){
        let when = DispatchTime.now() + 2
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) { [weak self] in
            self?.name = "delayed"

            print(self?.name )
        }
    }
    deinit {
        print("Person class is deinited \(self)")
    }
}
```

I create an instance of `Person` in the viewController below:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var p1 :Person? = Person(name: "MMM")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var persons : [Person] = []

        p1!.doWithDelay()

        persons.append(p1!)


        var p3 = Person(name: "OOO") // AAA

        persons.removeAll()

    }

}
```

If I have `var p3 = Person(name: "OOO")` then my `p1` instance *will* get deallocated, however if I comment out line AAA or simply replace it with `var p3 = "howareyou"` then my instance `Person` instance *won't* get deallocated at all.

Why?!

Comment: What part of the behavior is surprising? If you have a `var p3 = Person`, that person gets deallocated. If you don't, there's nothing to deallocate. In either case, your instance `var p1` won't get deallocated until the controller does, because the controller is holding onto it.

Comment: Responding to your recent edit: no, your `p1` instance *isn't* getting deallocated. `p3` is, because it's a local variable. Try printing the name of the person inside `deinit`.

Comment: @ConnorNeville  Thanks. yeah I was thinking `p1` was getting deallocated. One more question. I just appended `p3` to `persons` but still it was getting deallocated. Isn't `persons` suppose to hold onto `p3`?  I've read all about [ARC](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html)...from what I understand it's that: `persons` will increase the retain count of `p3` but not sure what happens after that.

Comment: @Honey `persons` is also a local variable, and therefore will be deinitialised  at the end of the method scope, therefore decrementing the retain count of all its elements, thus allowing your `p3` instance to be deallocated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot tell one person from another. Rewrite your Person class like this:

```
class Person: NSObject{
    var name: String?

    init(name: String){
        self.name = name
        super.init()
        NSLog("%@", "Person class is inited \(self)")
    }
    func doWithDelay(){
        let when = DispatchTime.now() + 2
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) { [weak self] in
            self?.name = "delayed"

            print(self?.name )
        }
    }
    deinit {
        NSLog("%@", "Person class is deinited \(self)")
    }
}
```

The difference here is (1) we log during `init` as well as `dealloc`, and (2) we derive from NSObject because it gives us a unique identifier for `self`, namely its memory address. We then get:

> ```
> Person class is inited
> <MyApp.Person: 0x618000047470> 
> Person class is inited 
> <MyApp.Person: 0x61000004b040> 
> Person class is deinited 
> <MyApp.Person: 0x61000004b040>
> ```

And that is exactly what we expect to see: the instance property Person persists, but the local variable Property is created and immediately destroyed again. Local variables are *automatic*: they are deallocated as soon as we reach the end of their scope (the containing curly braces), and so an object referred to by a local variable vanishes unless you have arranged for a longer-lived reference to retain it.

Comment: You might want to read my book's section on this topic: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch03.html#_variable_scope_and_lifetime

Comment: *"NSLog ... gives us a unique identifier for self"* – you would get the same output with `print("Person class is inited \(self)")`.

Comment: @MartinR But only if we derive from NSObject, yes?

Comment: Sure (related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32797561/1187415) – But it sounds as if you are claiming that  NSLog is required to get that description with the memory address. Perhaps I misunderstood you.

Comment: @MartinR obiouvsly you can also do `Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque()` which looks a little weird though

Comment: @Honey: Have a look at the Swift 3 code in http://stackoverflow.com/a/32801695/1187415 :)