# Getting the identifier of a touch

Tags: ios, swift, multi-touch, uitouch

I am trying to identify a touch throughout `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved` and `touchesEnded`.

When printing the `UITouch` (the entire set) to the console I noticed a String at the beginning, that seems to remain constant for each finger on the screen.

```
[<UITouch: 0x100d362e0> phase: ...
```

**How do I retrieve this property?**

Comment: UITouch is subclass of NSObject.you can access its property and print them.

Comment: `0x100d362e0` is the memory address of the object (compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32797561/how-can-you-mimic-the-description-output), but I doubt that you need it. You can compare two instances with `===`.

Comment: @TejasArdeshna i know how to access a property. I just can't seem to find the one that contains the code snippet I posted.

Comment: Why do you want identify the touch? The hardware itself cannot do it if two fingers move too close together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you are asking but think you can use this as a start to tracking unique touch instances, though I'm not sure how reliable it will be given that we don't create the touch event.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var touches: [UITouch] = []

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.touches.append(contentsOf: touches)
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        touches.forEach {
            let index = self.touches.index(of: $0)
            print(String.init(describing: index))
        }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        touches.forEach {
            let index = self.touches.index(of: $0)
            print(String.init(describing: index))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To identity the UITouch I would use hash value

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    event?.allTouches?.forEach {
        print("touch began for: \($0.hash)")
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    event?.allTouches?.forEach {
        print("touch move for: \($0.hash)")
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    event?.allTouches?.forEach {
        print("touch end for: \($0.hash)")
    }
}

override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    event?.allTouches?.forEach {
        print("touch cancelled for: \($0.hash)")
    }
}
```

Comment: While the chosen answer apparently solved the poster’s issue, this answer actually answers the question asked. 